# Delete record without a page refresh with ajax in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am working on a Cakephp 2.x but I don't think the problem has anything to do with the Cakephp. I want to delete a file without a page refresh.

**HTML / PHP :**

```
<div class = "success" style="display:none;">Deleted successfully </div>
<div class = "error" style="display:none;">Error  </div>    

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button icon-trash" title = "delete" onclick="openConfirm('<?php echo $filename; ?>','<?php echo $idImage; ?>');"></a>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function openConfirm(filename, idImage) {
    $.modal.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the file?', function () {
        deleteFile(filename, idImage);
    }, function () {

    });
};

function deleteFile(filename, idImage) {
    var filename = filename;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            idImage: idImage
        },
        url: "http://localhost/bugshot/deleteFile/" + filename,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            } else {
                $(".error").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

my images which is in foreach loop 
this code is displaying the image

foreach($file as $files):?>

```
   <?php    $downloadUrl = array('controller' => 'bugshot', 'action' => 'downloadImages', $files['Image']['filename'], '?' => array('download' => true));
             $imageUrl = array('controller' => 'bugshot', 'action' => 'downloadImages', $files['Image']['filename']);

        ?>
 <?php  echo $this->Html->link(
            $this->Html->image($imageUrl),
            $downloadUrl,
            array('class' => 'frame', 'escape' => false)
        );?>
```

Delete link

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button icon-trash" title = "deleteImage" onclick="openConfirm('<?php echo $files['Image']['filename']; ?>','<?php echo $files['Image']['idImage'];; ?>');"></a>
```

The code works great except that after the image or record is deleted the record/image is still displayed on the page until it is refreshed. How do I fix this?

Comment: $('.image_or_file_selecor).hide(); Try this on ajax success

Comment: @IgnatB. the images are in foreach loop ... i mean there are multiple images on the page ..if i do in your way then it will hide other images too .. dont u think ?

Comment: You should consider using the link function in the JsHelper of cake http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::link

Comment: What does the for loop look like? How are the actual images displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove it with javascript.

```
$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
                $('img[src="/pathToImg/' + filename + '"]').remove(); // Remove by src
                // $('#' + idImage).remove(); // Remove by ID.
            } else {
                $(".error").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        }
        ...
    });
```

**Note :** `var filename = filename;` means nothing because you are assigning filename argument to a new variable with the same name. You can just remove it.

Comment: well the path is private .. not anybody can access the image .. the image is associated to a particular user ... so how can i give path here

Comment: $('#' + idImage').remove(); i want to use this method but what should i write here instead of hash'#'

Comment: thankyou ...i have done it by using ur method ... thankyou it works

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help. :)